# sending SignalR messages in WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, signalr

Hi I have a WCF service which receives requests from a web front end. The Service then connects to a SignalR hub and sends a message to a subscriber(s). This all works fine for single requests. However when I load the service with multiple requests (usually anymore than 8). signalR connections seem to drop and web clients are unable to connect to the Hub. After time this eventually frees up and clients start connecting again.

My assumption is that it is to do with the lifetime of my HubConnection in the WCF service. I have tried the following approaches to resolve this, but none seem to work. I'm sure I am missing something really obvious here.

Approach 1 - create connection, don't dispose and let it fall out of scope for the GC.

```
 // Establish connection to the SignalRHub.
        var hubConnection = new HubConnection(this.signalRHost + "/signalr", useDefaultUrl: false);
        hubConnection.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        IHubProxy hubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy(this.dataCollectionServiceHubName);

        // Start connection to signalR hub.
        hubConnection.Start().ContinueWith((result) =>
        {
            hubProxy.Invoke("SendAll", message);
        });
```

Approach 2 - call stop after the message has been sent.

```
// Establish connection to the SignalRHub.
        var hubConnection = new HubConnection(this.signalRHost + "/signalr", useDefaultUrl: false);
        hubConnection.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        IHubProxy hubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy(this.dataCollectionServiceHubName);

        // Start connection to signalR hub.
        hubConnection.Start().ContinueWith((result) =>
            {                    
                hubProxy.Invoke("SendAll", message).ContinueWith((r) => { hubConnection.Stop(); });
            });

    }
```

Approach 3 - crate connection in a Using Block so Dispose is called after send.

```
 using (var hubConnection = this.connectionFactory.Create())
        {
            // Establish connection to the SignalRHub.
            IHubProxy hubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy(this.dataCollectionServiceHubName);

            // Start connection to signalR hub.
            hubConnection.Start().ContinueWith((result) =>
            {                    
                hubProxy.Invoke("SendAll", message);
            });
        }
```

Approach 4 Create a singleton Hub

```
public sealed class SignalRConnectionFactory : ISignalRConnectionFactory
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The instance.
    /// </summary>
    private static volatile SignalRConnectionFactory instance;

    /// <summary>
    /// The sync root.
    /// </summary>
    private static object syncRoot = new Object();

    /// <summary>
    /// The signal r host.
    /// </summary>
    private string signalRHost = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SignalRHost"];

    /// <summary>
    /// The hub connection.
    /// </summary>
    private HubConnection hubConnection;

    /// <summary>
    /// Prevents a default instance of the <see cref="SignalRConnectionFactory"/> class from being created.
    /// </summary>
    private SignalRConnectionFactory()
    {
        this.hubConnection = new HubConnection(this.signalRHost + "/signalr", useDefaultUrl: false);
        this.hubConnection.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the instance.
    /// </summary>
    public static SignalRConnectionFactory Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                lock (syncRoot)
                {
                    if (instance == null)
                    {
                        instance = new SignalRConnectionFactory();
                    }
                }
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The create.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// The <see cref="HubConnection"/>.
    /// </returns>
    public HubConnection Create()
    {
        return this.hubConnection;
    }
}
using (var hubConnection = this.connectionFactory.Create())
        {
            // Establish connection to the SignalRHub.
            IHubProxy hubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy(this.dataCollectionServiceHubName);


            // Start connection to signalR hub.
            hubConnection.Start().ContinueWith((result) =>
            {                    
                hubProxy.Invoke("SendAll", message);
            });
        }
```

Comment: Are you creating a connection per WCF request? This would be very expensive. Have you thought about having on connection that lives for the entire life time of the service?

Comment: Currently yes the connection is created per request, which is expensive. The question is how to keep the connection alive for all requests. A singleton Factory that passes the same connected instance to the service or setting the WCF service in InstanceContextMode.Single. I worry about performance with the second approach.